# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')

Tags: javascript, node.js

After doing some web scraping I am loading the json object using:

```
  const myJson = await JSON.parse(jsonInString);
```

I am then trying to define a number of properties for db storage with code such as:

```
    lat2 = location.address.coordinate.lat ;
    lon2 = location.address.coordinate.lon ;
```

I'm getting the error in the title. After some investigation I can see that in the cases where this fails, the address object is not defined. Is there a way to avoid the error in node/js without something like:

```
if (location && location.address && location.address.coordinate ...) {
           lat2 = location.address.coordinate.lat ;
}
```

Comment: In ES6 you can use optional chaining: `lat2 = location?.address?.coordinate?.lat;`

Comment: Note there is no reason to `await` `JSON.parse`. It is not an `async` function and does not return a Promise.